# Spyder python console output

Tags: python, console, output, spyder

I have a simple quesiton.. I understand that python console is removed for the recent Spyder versions. Is there a way to display outputs that would have been displayed in python console?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't understand what you mean. Please provide an example of what you have in mind.

Comment: Okay, I use a C++ based python API package called rdkit. When warning and errors are outputted from C++ code, it used to be printed out to python console, so I used to use that to catch errors. With python console gone, I have no way to see these errors. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a problem with the IPython console, already reported [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3777). It'll be fixed in Spyder 4.